# C#: What is the proper way to swap winform controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

What is the proper way to replace one winform element with another element when something is triggered? For example, I would like to replace a button with a text box in the same position and the same dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not (for some reason) want to simply change their visibility, you can add and remove them from the form's Controls collection.

```
// contrived example...
private void Swap( Control toAdd, Control toRemove )
{
    this.Controls.Remove( toRemove );
    this.Controls.Add( toAdd );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put them both there, and play with visability

Answer (score 1):

Put them next to each other and use the Visible property to hide one (Visible=false) and display the other (Visible=true).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching them out, I'm using a tab control with the tab buttons hidden, programmatically switching between the tabs on which my different controls are displayed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255600/winforms-hiding-tabcontrol-headers).