# PowerShell .NET Navigating within forms

Tags: .net, forms, powershell, user-interface

When one creates a form and wants to navigate by clicking a button on that form, is it needed to create a whole new form to bring up the next page? Or can the current form be reinitialized in some way with other buttons on it?

When clicking the button 'Active Directory' you can see that the form is reloading or redrawing itself. As I'm not really experienced with this and information on navigation within forms is difficult to find, it would be nice if someone could tell me if this is the way to do it properly?

Because every time you go into a menu, you need to create a totally new form which makes room for errors, as you want things (like 'not able to maximize, icon, title bar, exit button, back button, ...') to be the same all over the different windows.

For the second window, 'Active Directory' I tried things like `StartPosition = 'CenterParent'` but this didn't work as it showed up on a totally different spot then it's parent closed.

Thanks you for your help.

**The code:**

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$WindowTitle = 'Script center'
$Title = 'Welcome to Script Center'
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("S:\Prod\Script center\Background.jpg")

# Main menu
$MenuBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MenuBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(650,450)
$MenuBox.Text = $WindowTitle
$MenuBox.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$MenuBox.MaximizeBox = $False
$MenuBox.AutoSize = $False
$MenuBox.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$MenuBox.Icon = $Icon
$MenuBox.BackgroundImage = $Image
$MenuBox.BackgroundImageLayout = 'None' # None, Tile, Center, Stretch, Zoom

# Exit Button
$ExitButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExitButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(540,370)
$ExitButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$ExitButton.Text = 'Exit'
$ExitButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",11,0,3,1)
$ExitButton.Add_Click({
    Remove-Item "$WorkingDirectory\Temp\*.*" -Force
    $MenuBox.Close()
})

# Main menu Header Text
$MenuHeader = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MenuHeader.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,1,3,1)
$MenuHeader.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(118,20)
$MenuHeader.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40) 
$MenuHeader.Text = $Title
$MenuHeader.BackColor = 'Transparent'
$MenuHeader.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($MenuHeader)

# Main menu
$BoxLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BoxLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",10,0,3,1)
$BoxLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
$BoxLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(680,20) 
$BoxLabel.Text = 'Select the category:'
$BoxLabel.BackColor = 'Transparent'
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($BoxLabel)

# AD menu
$ADBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(650,450)
$ADBox.Text = $WindowTitle
$ADBox.StartPosition = 'CenterParent'
$ADBox.AutoSize = $False
$ADBox.MaximizeBox = $False
$ADBox.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$ADBox.Icon = $Icon
$ADBox.BackgroundImage = $Image

# AD button 1
$ADButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ADButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,160)
$ADButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$ADButton1.Add_Click({
    $global:ButtonResult = 'Result: AD Button 1'
    $MenuBox.Close()
})
$ADButton1.Text = 'AD Button 1'
$ADButton1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$ADBox.Controls.Add($ADButton1)
$ADBox.Controls.Add($ExitButton)

# Main menu button 1
$Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,100)
$Button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$Button2.Add_Click({
    # Call Sub menu 1
    $MenuBox.Close()
    $MenuBox.Dispose()
    $ADBox.Topmost = $True
    $ADBox.Add_Shown({$ADBox.Activate()})
    [void] $ADBox.ShowDialog()
})
$Button2.Text = 'Active directory'
$Button2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Button2)

# Main menu button 2
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,160)
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$Button1.Add_Click({
    $global:ButtonResult = 'Result: Button 1'
    $MenuBox.Close()
})
$Button1.Text = 'Files and Folders'
$Button1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Button1)

$MenuBox.Controls.Add($ExitButton)

# Show Menu
$MenuBox.Topmost = $True
$MenuBox.Add_Shown({$MenuBox.Activate()})
[void] $MenuBox.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Though this is all possible with PowerShell, I wonder if you should be doing this with Visual Studio and a proper forms designer as it sounds fairly complex. In this scenario I'd have thought it better to have multiple panels in a single form which you show / hide during navigation

Comment: Thank you arco444, I've just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038772/how-to-hide-tabs-on-powershell-gui) as an example on how to work with panels. I'm still trying to figure it out. In the meantime I'm also taking a look at Visual Studio to see if it's easier with this tool to create a proper form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made something myself, hope it's useful for you guys:

```
Function Open-Form {

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing') | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() | Out-Null

$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + '\powershell.exe')
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile('S:\Prod\Script center\Background.jpg')

$PanelLocation = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(122,60)
$PanelSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(535,390)
$ButtonSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35)
$PanelBackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::CornflowerBlue

# Navigation
$ButtonHome_OnClick  = {$PanelHome.Visible=$true;$PanelAD.Visible = $false;$PanelFF.Visible = $false;$PanelAbout=$false}
$ButtonAD_OnClick    = {$PanelHome.Visible=$false;$PanelAD.Visible = $true;$PanelFF.Visible = $false;$PanelAbout=$false}
$ButtonFF_OnClick    = {$PanelHome.Visible=$false;$PanelAD.Visible = $false;$PanelFF.Visible = $True;$PanelAbout=$false}
$ButtonAbout_OnClick = {$PanelHome.Visible=$false;$PanelAD.Visible = $false;$PanelFF.Visible = $false;$PanelAbout=$true}

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,474)
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.AutoSize = $False
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Icon = $Icon
$Form.BackgroundImage = $Image
$Form.Text = 'Script Center'
$Form.TopMost = $True
$Form.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

$TextTop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TextTop.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,1,3,1)
$TextTop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1,20)
$TextTop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40) 
$TextTop.Text = 'Welcome to Script Center'
$TextTop.BackColor = 'Transparent'
$TextTop.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
$Form.Controls.Add($TextTop)

$ButtonHome = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonHome.Text = 'Home'
$ButtonHome.TabIndex = 2
$ButtonHome.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ButtonHome.add_Click($ButtonHome_OnClick)
$ButtonHome.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,60)
$ButtonHome.Size = $ButtonSize
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonHome)

$ButtonAD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonAD.Text = 'Active Directory'
$ButtonAD.TabIndex = 3
$ButtonAD.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ButtonAD.add_Click($ButtonAD_OnClick)
$ButtonAD.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,100)
$ButtonAD.Size = $ButtonSize
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonAD)

$ButtonFF = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonFF.Text = 'Files and Folders'
$ButtonFF.TabIndex = 4
$ButtonFF.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ButtonFF.add_Click($ButtonFF_OnClick)
$ButtonFF.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,140)
$ButtonFF.Size = $ButtonSize
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonFF)

$ButtonAbout = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonAbout.Text = 'About'
$ButtonAbout.TabIndex = 7
$ButtonAbout.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$ButtonAbout.add_Click($ButtonAbout_OnClick)
$ButtonAbout.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,414)
$ButtonAbout.Size = $ButtonSize
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonAbout)

# Panel 1: Home
$PanelHome = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$PanelHome.Location = $PanelLocation
$PanelHome.Size = $PanelSize
$PanelHome.TabIndex = 8
#$PanelHome.BackgroundImage = $Image
#$PanelHome.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Zoom' # None, Tile, Center, Stretch, Zoom
$PanelHome.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
$PanelHome.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Controls.Add($PanelHome)

# Panel 2: Active Directory
$PanelAD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$PanelAD.Location = $PanelLocation
$PanelAD.Size = $PanelSize
$PanelAD.TabIndex = 8
$PanelAD.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Controls.Add($PanelAD)

$PanelADTabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$PanelADTabControl.TabIndex = 4
$PanelADTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0
$PanelADTabControl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$PanelADTabControl.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(535,390)
$PanelAD.Controls.Add($PanelADTabControl)

$PanelADTab1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$PanelADTab1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$PanelADTab1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(205,445) 
$PanelADTab1.TabIndex = 2
$PanelADTab1.Text = 'Users without manager'
$PanelADTab1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$PanelADTab1.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
$PanelADTabControl.Controls.Add($PanelADTab1)

$PanelADTab2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$PanelADTab2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4,22)
$PanelADTab2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(205,445) 
$PanelADTab2.TabIndex = 2
$PanelADTab2.Text = 'Inconsistencies'
$PanelADTab2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$PanelADTab2.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
$PanelADTabControl.Controls.Add($PanelADTab2)

# Panel 3: Files and Folders
$PanelFF = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$PanelFF.Location = $PanelLocation
$PanelFF.Size = $PanelSize
$PanelFF.TabIndex = 8
$PanelFF.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
$PanelFF.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Controls.Add($PanelFF)

$PanelFFTxt = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
#$PanelFFTxt.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,1,3,1)
$PanelFFTxt.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1,20)
$PanelFFTxt.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40) 
$PanelFFTxt.Text = 'This is the panel for Files and Folders'
$PanelFFTxt.BackColor = 'Transparent'
$PanelFFTxt.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
$PanelFF.Controls.Add($PanelFFTxt)

# Panel X: About
$PanelAbout = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$PanelAbout.Location = $PanelLocation
$PanelAbout.Size = $PanelSize
$PanelAbout.TabIndex = 8
$PanelAbout.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
$PanelAbout.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Controls.Add($PanelAbout)

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(589,458)
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,15)
$ProgressBar.TabIndex = 0
$Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)

$StatusBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar
$StatusBar.Text = 'StatusBar'
$StatusBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,456)
$StatusBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,18)
$StatusBar.TabIndex = 1
$Form.Controls.Add($StatusBar)

$Form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
}

Open-Form
```