# Powershell GUI tabbed layout script placement

Tags: powershell, user-interface, tabs

I wrote six small gui scripts that I'd like to place in a single file, for the sake of converting said file into rxecutable with ps2exe.

I've found a script ,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038772/how-to-hide-tabs-on-powershell-gui) on stack that is perfect for what I want. Unfortunatelly I cann't find any info on script placement within tabs and MS documentation leads me to ISE tabs, which is not helpfull.

Say I'd like to place this

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

    $button_click = {
        $folder = $textBox1.Text;
        
          $pytanie = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Czy chcesz usunac folder?', '', '4');
           If($pytanie -eq 'Yes')
           {Remove-Item –path $folder –recurse -Force};
           $test = Test-Path $folder;
           if ($test -eq $false){[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Folder Usuniety', '', '0')}}
    
    $label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label2.AutoSize = $True
    $label2.Text = ("Scieżka")
    $label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10,30)
    $label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (25,70)
    $label2.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    
    $textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70) ### Location of the text box
    $textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,50) ### Size of the text box
    $textBox1.Multiline = $false ### Allows multiple lines of data
    $textBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $textBox1.ReadOnly=$false
    
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
    $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (200,30)
    $button.Text = "Usun Folder"
    $button.Add_Click($button_click)
    
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = 'Mapowanie' ### Text to be displayed in the title
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,200) ### Size of the window
    $form.StartPosition = 'Manual'
    $form.Location      = '10,10'
    $form.Topmost = $true  ### Optional - Opens on top of other windows
    
    
    $form.Controls.AddRange(@($textBox1,$button, $label2))
    
    
    
    $form.ShowDialog()
```

within a tab. How to do it?

Comment: You need to add a TabControl object and then add pages (tabs) with the formatting, controls, etc. From experience it might be worth starting from scratch instead of trying to adapt your current script to a tabbed GUI. It will give you way better insight into how they work.

Comment: I agree that it might be more effective to start from scratch and I don't mind that. But the question still remains. How do I place objects i.e. text boxes, buttons into the tab?

Could you pint me to some documentation?

Comment: This is a nice tutorial using WPF and XAML, it will surely give you a boost as you won't have to declare too much controls, part IV is your goal: https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope.html

Comment: Thank you @alexzelaya, I will read this when I get some free time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it the

```
$Tab1.Controls.Add($button)
```

You are looking for.

For example

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$ApplicationForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ApplicationForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ApplicationForm.Topmost = $false 
$ApplicationForm.Size = "800,600"

$FormTabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl 
$FormTabControl.Size = "755,475" 
$FormTabControl.Location = "25,75" 
$ApplicationForm.Controls.Add($FormTabControl)

$Tab1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
$Tab1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Tab1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True 
$Tab1.Name = "Tab1" 
$Tab1.Text = "Tab1” 
$FormTabControl.Controls.Add($Tab1)

$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70) ### Location of the text box
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,50) ### Size of the text box
$textBox1.Multiline = $false ### Allows multiple lines of data
$textBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$textBox1.ReadOnly=$false
$Tab1.Controls.Add($textBox1)


$Tab2 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
$Tab2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Tab2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True 
$Tab2.Name = "Tab2" 
$Tab2.Text = "Tab2” 
$FormTabControl.Controls.Add($Tab2)

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (200,30)
$button.Text = "Usun Folder"
$button.Add_Click($button_click)
$Tab2.Controls.Add($button)

# Initlize the form
$ApplicationForm.Add_Shown({$ApplicationForm.Activate()})
[void] $ApplicationForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is a more immediate solution