# Can I mimic this option dialog window using C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

This is what the option dialog window looks like in Outlook 2010. I wonder how I can create a similar option window with C# WinForm controls.

Looking at it first, I thought it kinda works like `TabControl`. But `TabControl` doesn't seem to offer Left/Right panel layout.

Then, I thought of `SplitContainer` control and could probably take advantage of it, where the left panel could be having a list of menu buttons, and the right panel displaying the option details.

However, here also comes the problems, how can I create menu buttons that look like those in the screenshot then?

Perhaps, there're some existing controls that I am missing. If WinForm doesn't look good here, what else could I try?

Comment: This is a better way to hide the headers [link][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6954785/1750895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TabControl, hide all of it's tabs. Add a ListView with the tab names to the left and change active tab when list view selection changes.

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to find a way to hide the tab. I do find the alignment property though. By setting alignment value to left, I can have tab displayed to the left side.

Comment: Here are some options to hide tab heades - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255600/winforms-hiding-tabcontrol-headers

Comment: this option becomes bad when you have many controls. if you change the property of a control in the form with say 300 controls, in some cases, it would take 10 - 20 seconds to effect

Answer (score 0):

Just like alex stated you are on the right track, add a splitcontainer, place the listview in the right and create a new control component for the special Tab (with no header) and place the new Tabcontrol in the left. I particularly like this method of creating this special tab: 
[TabControlNoHeader](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/215150/panels-or-a-tab-control). It gives you option to enable header or not.