# Does anyone know to create a winforms (C#) prefrerences GUI like this

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a novice programmer, wanted to develop a module preferably for my application using C #, which has an interface similar to the image I'm showing. The main curiosity is that it has a similar style navigation.

Image Details:
[image: images]

Comment: If you look on CodeProject, you will see 100's of people have already done this. :)

Comment: Pretty much like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494451/can-i-mimic-this-option-dialog-window-using-c-sharp-winform/15494532#15494532 , but with LargeIcons mode for list view.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a ListView control on the left.  It has a view mode where it shows large icons and text like that.