# The proper way to navigate forms in C# (Hierarchical/Content-driven navigation)

Tags: c#, winforms

If I were to navigate between 2 forms (or more), it would be like this:

**Main Menu to second form:**

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this) // Instantiate form and pass form data to next form
Hide();
```

**Second form:**

```
Form1 form;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1; //Take in previous form's data
}
```

Navigating forward will `Hide()` the current form while navigating backwards will `Close()` the current form.

But what if I am in the 3rd, 4th... nth form and I wish to go back to the main menu? Is there some kind of way to close all of my hidden forms?

Or is there a proper method to navigate between forms?

Comment: Perhaps [MDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better approach?

Comment: @Groo Interesting, but my application does not require any menustrips or toolstrips.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use Interfaces to change data between forms. This let's you stay more independent and your Form2 just get the data it needs. For example:

```
public interface IForm1 //You should find better naming
{
  void Edit(); //Method for edit some data
  List<T> DataList {get;} //List with some relevant data
}

public Form Form1 : IForm1
{
   public void Edit(){ //Your edit logic}
   public List<T> DataList {get{return myGrid.DataSource as List<T>;}}
}

public Form Form2
{
  private IForm1 formData;

  public Form2(IForm1 formData)
  {
     formData = formData;
  }
}
```

Further i would think about your idea to have so much forms. I think one MainForm with a TabControl as first element is better way to go in many cases. You can create a UserControl for each TabPage and just switch the TabPage instead of poping up Forms all the time.

**UPDATE**

[image]

This Picture maybe clarify what i mean. The TabPageHeader are all invisible (in image i make it visible for clarification). If Login succeed you just switch the TabPage.
`TabControl.SelectedTabPage = tabPageMainScreen;`

So it feels more fluent to the user and you don't have the problem you describe. But i would recommend to separate the Form by different UserControls to keep it simple.

**UPDATE 2**

On Winforms you can hide the TabHeader as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255600/winforms-hiding-tabcontrol-headers).
Example:

```
tabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

It's a bit ugly that the default TabControl don't has regular way but it works fine.

Comment: The reason why i need many forms is that my test project contains a huge storyboard. Take a look at a small part of my storyboard here http://imgur.com/a/NbPxv

Comment: @Kuyo you could also use one form with TabControl for your purpose. Just set all TabPages.Visible = false and show only the one you want. This disable the permanent popup of forms. If you want the mass Form solution, i would prefer one MainForm which opens another Form via ShowDialog() and get the result back.

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a try later on. :)

Comment: I just saw your updated answer. I can understand why you suggested TabControl. Indeed it is useful for my purpose but I went to search up online about how to hide the tab page headers. There doesn't seem to have a property to hide them. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Much thanks. I would like to ask, do most people usually do their applications with only one main form and all their "pages" inside it? While I know that having many forms result in a "popping up" visual kind of application, I would want to fully understand how use Windows Forms the right way.

Comment: @Kuyo I'm not sure how the Most People do it. But it's common pattern. I think the most big programs use Frameworks. So we use Devexpress or Telerik is common as well. There you can do this by default (Make TabHeader invisible etc.). I don't think there is the one right way. But in past we see our users hate this popups.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view model from the data in the first form and then supply it in a method on the second form.

```
public class Form1ViewModel {
     public int Age {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
//method on Form1
public void NavigateToForm2()
{
    var vm = new Form1ViewModel{ Age = 32, Name = "Test name"};
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.SetViewModel(vm);
    form2.Show();
}
```

Also to close the forms take a look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would recommend taking a look into MVVM pattern because that handles the navigation, instantiation of the forms (views). A library to start with is [mvvmfx](http://mvvmfx.codeplex.com/). There are also other libraries for MVVM.

Comment: MVVM is best approach but you will need some Frameworks for WinForms because it's design. WPF introduced this pattern very well. But thanks @Mihail Stancescu i will take a look at your named frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

While Sebi and Mihail has given great ways for a proper navigation, I have did some practice on my own and found several solutions.

As what Sebi mentioned, a `TabControl` with one main form is the better way to go in many cases as it is more fluent, does not have forms popping up all the time.

Another way is to only preserve the instance of your parent(main) form:

> Navigating from a child form to another will pass the parent form and values of your data (if required), before closing the form (Once closed, all resources created is disposed).
>
> However in some cases where you need to maintain the values for a previous child form (So that all user input does not need to be re-entered again), You have to also pass the child form and hide it instead of closing it.

One thing that confused me when I opened the question was that I had initially thought that navigating forward in forms should always use `Hide();`, and not `Close();`.

To close all forms except the main form (Might be useful for those who have a similar design concept as mine):

```
List<string> currentform = new List<string>();

foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form.Name != "Form1")
    {
        currentform.Add(form.Name);
    }
}

foreach (string formName in currentform)
{
    Application.OpenForms[formName].Close();
}
```