# Removing tabs in tabcontrol and using designated buttons to switch between tabs

Tags: vb.net, tabs, tabcontrol

I'm currently working on an application for Windows, however, I have one small problem: I can't seem to figure this one out...

Is there a way to remove the tab headers from tab control and designate other buttons to switch between tabs? I'm going for a more modern look and the default tabs in tab control are not at all what I'm interested in.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: `tabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;`  Use the DrawItem event.

Comment: Have you tried the `TabControl.Appearance` property? You can turn the tabs into buttons or flat buttons.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers on this question!

I've just thought of a different method to keep the clean look of my program without having to get too complicated with code.

For anyone wondering about this, you could set different buttons to hide and show different things, for example:

Under homeBtn you could have code that shows the information shown on the page by default, yet at the same time, you could also hide any information from the previous tab.

Thanks, Laugh

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add buttons setting the property `SelectedIndex` on the tab control to switch the pages. To hide the tab headers, there are some ideas over [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255600/winforms-hiding-tabcontrol-headers)